# How to run a script before and after a Python expression is executed in Django shell?

Tags: python, django, ipython, django-extensions

I want to make Django's management command `shell` to run a script **before and after** every Python expression is executed. For example:

(Think of I'm using command `python3 manage.py shell --ipython` to get into shell.)

```
In [1]: from api.models import Student
In [2]: new_student = Student.objects.create(name="John Doe", number=123)
In [3]: new_student.number
Out[3]: 123
In [4]: new_student.name
Out[4]: "John Doe"
```

I want to send the expressions and outputs of them to a **Slack channel**.To do that, I need to run a Python script before and after **every expression** which takes expressions or outputs to log to my Slack channel.

For the example above, the script would log expressions, for example `"new_student.number"`, and their outputs -if exist, of course-, for exapmle `"123"`, **to the Slack channel**.

I've tried using [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) module, used its `shell_plus` command with **pre and post signals**. But it was only calling the signals **before and after running the plus_shell**. Therefore, what I want to do was running those signal handlers **before and after every command/expression**.

Is there a way to achieve this using a configuration, a module or even writing a custom management command?

Comment: Why don't you create a python [decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#simple-decorators) ?

Comment: If you mean that decorating the custom command handler function, it cannot help me to log expressions. It would be nice if I wanted to log executed management commands, not expressions I type in the Django shell.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if the shell would really support it the way you want but there's a quick hack you can do by writing a wrapper function and then calling all commands via that wrapper function.

```py
def wrap_fun(expr):
    val=exec(expr)
    ## run/call your script with argument expr and val
    print(val)
```

and then calling all your functions as

```py
In [1]: wrap_fun('from api.models import Student')
In [2]: wrap_fun('new_student = Student.objects.create(name="John Doe", number=123)')
In [3]: wrap_fun('new_student.number')
Out[3]: 123
In [4]: wrap_fun('new_student.name')
Out[4]: "John Doe"
```

You can use the `subprocess` module to load your python script(which sends slack messages) and call it. Alternatively, you can add this function and slack script to your Django project in a module, control the sending behaviour via local setting like `DEBUG=true` and then call it directly from the shell.